# How would I make a Yes/No prompt in Console using C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm mostly new to C# and I've been writing code to practice.

I've written some code where you enter a line of text, or a "login key", and I want to make it where you can confirm that login key.

Here's the code I've done so far, I will use "//" on the part I'm stuck on. (Wont include any unnecessary code.)

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a login key.");

    string Key = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("You entered, " + Key + " as your login key!");

    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? "); // This is where I'm stuck at, got no idea how to do a yes/no prompt.
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can easily go overboard on these Console login scripts. Here's my contribution:

```
bool confirmed = false;
string Key;
do {
    Console.Write("Please enter a login key: ");
    Key = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You entered, " + Key + " as your login key!");

    ConsoleKey response;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] ");
        response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;   // true is intercept key (dont show), false is show
        if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            Console.WriteLine();

    } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);

    confirmed = response == ConsoleKey.Y;
} while (!confirmed);
Console.WriteLine("You chose {0}!", Key);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Sample output:

```
Please enter a login key: potato
You entered, potato as your login key!
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] a
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] s
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] l
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] d
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] k
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] f
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] d
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] n
Please enter a login key: banana
You entered, banana as your login key!
Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [y/n] y
You chose banana!
```

Answer (score 10):

I remake it like a utils class I hope it's gonna be usefull:

```
class UtilsConsole
{
        public static bool Confirm(string title)
        {
            ConsoleKey response;
            do
            {
                Console.Write($"{ title } [y/n] ");
                response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;  
                if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);

            return (response == ConsoleKey.Y);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Console.ReadKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx);

```
Console.WriteLine("Press 'y' if you would like awesome!");

ConsoleKeyInfo cki =    Console.ReadKey();

if (cki.Key.ToString() == "y")
{
        //do what you need for yes
}else {
     // presses something other then Y
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to create a reusable method to handle all future questions. Very simplified version to illustrate basics.

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(PromptConfirmation("Did you answer yes?"))
    {
        //todo: Handle positive response
    }
}

private bool PromptConfirmation(string confirmText)
{
    Console.Write(confirmText + " [y/n] : ");
    ConsoleKey response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
    Console.WriteLine();
    return (response == ConsoleKey.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop

```
bool confirmed = false;

while(!confirmed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a login key.");
    string Key = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You entered, " + Key + " as your login key!");
    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to choose this as your login key? [yes/no]");

    string option = Console.ReadLine();

    if (option == "yes")
    {
        confirmed = true;
    }

}
```

This way if `option` is anything but `yes` it will remain in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Console Prompt [Yes/No]` with my addition being that it can have a `default response`

```
public static bool Question(string question, bool defaultYes = true, bool useDefaultAnswer = true)
{
    bool setDefault = false;
    ConsoleKey keyboardResponse;

    do
    {
        Console.Write($"{question} [Y/N] ");

        if (useDefaultAnswer && !setDefault)
        {
            setDefault = true;

            if (defaultYes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Y");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("N");
            }
        }

        keyboardResponse = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;

        if (keyboardResponse != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            if (useDefaultAnswer)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (keyboardResponse != ConsoleKey.Y && keyboardResponse != ConsoleKey.N);

    if (useDefaultAnswer && keyboardResponse == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (defaultYes)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return keyboardResponse == ConsoleKey.Y;
}
```

I have tested this pretty heavily it works well